# Pop up different Div if the user has not sign up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div functioning as a button and whenever you click this div a pop up div or a light box div will show up with some information such as the product that you are going to buy and the list of product you have bought so far from this website.

I want that, if the user who clicks that button is not a registered user or has not logged in yet, then the button will show up **a different light box div or pop up div that will ask them to sign up or to sign in**.

This is the html Code with only one pop up div to show the information of the registered user:

---

```
    <p> 
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                                             document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">ADD TO BAG</a></p>




    <!--Pop Up Div-->       
<div id="light" class="white_content" alt="botton">This is the user information. 


        <p><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
                                             document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></p>

</div>
<!--End of Pop Up Div-->        

<div id="fade" class="black_overlay" onLoad="initDynamicOptionLists()"></div>
```

Thank you very much for helping me! :)

Comment: And what is the problem? You simply need to determine if user is logged in and wrap your div-showing function in an `if` statement where you choose which one (of the divs) you actually want to show. If your problem is how to check if user is logged in, then you have several options: 1) set a variable in the script when generating HTML code in PHP; 2) send an AJAX request to the server and there check if the session is set; 3) set a cookie on login, and in javascript check if that cookie exists.

Comment: what will be used to define user login status?

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk thank you for the explanation, I can vote you up if you hit that in the answer box.

Comment: @charlietfl what we used to use?

Comment: @inandout, thanks. No need for that, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you must be used any session or cookies that hold value about the user, if user is logged in so you can set cookies and session that indicate current present user is log in,and you check condition before the page load the user is logged in or not

```
<script>
<?
if(isset($_SESSION["logornot"]))
{
echo "var $check=1";
}
else
{
echo "var $check=0";
}
?>
if($check==1)
{
// user is log in.. do your task here..
}
else
{
//user is not log in.. do your task here...
}
</script>
```

thank you..

Comment: if check = 1, then the pop up div is shown, and else for that different pop up div? Thank you. :)

Comment: How about the html mark up, how to set the pop up divs there?

Comment: @inandout you can write code of showing the div box in if part if user is log in and write the code of showing the div box in else part if user can not log in thank you

Comment: @inandout i can not understand your second question, please give something more description please

Comment: visit here: http://jsfiddle.net/UJE4R/ thank you